# Casting synchronized on collection returned object

Tags: java, collections, synchronized

I am learning about multithreading and am having trouble understanding synchronization while working with `LinkedHashMap` specifically in regards to my code, what is getting locked. Is the object retrieved from the `proxyAutoMap` getting locked or is the entire `proxyAutoMap` instance getting locked?

Note: `AutoMap` is simply a `LinkedHashMap` hash map for storing objects

Below is some code for reference:

```
public abstract class ProxyAutomobile {
    protected static AutoMap<Automobile> proxyAutoMap = new AutoMap<Automobile>();

    public void printAuto(String key) {
        try {
            synchronized (proxyAutoMap.getAuto(key)) {
                proxyAutoMap.getAuto(key).print();
            }
        } catch (AutoException ae ) {
            ae.fix(ae.getErrorID());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are locking on an object which was put into `proxyAutoMap` for key `key`.

Comment: This will throw a NullPointerException if there is no object for this key (but so would the `print` in the following line)